# camera2 : Problems with focused area and focus distance

Tags: android, focus, distance, area, android-camera2

I tried many time to set a distance focus on camera2 API, or set autofocus just on a specific area initialized at the start of the activity.

But it still not working...

Could you help me please ? :)

here is my configuration :

```
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);

        MeteringRectangle[] focusArea = new MeteringRectangle[1];
        focusArea[0] = new MeteringRectangle(new Rect(rectangle.getLeft(),rectangle.getTop(),
                rectangle.getRight(), rectangle.getBottom()), MeteringRectangle.METERING_WEIGHT_MAX);
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, focusArea);  
      //captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE,10000000000.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the code where you call either CameraCaptureSession.capture or setRepeatingRequest.  But you should not set TRIGGER_START in a repeating request, since that'll restart focus on every frame.  Only use it in a single capture() call.

Also, did you mean you change CONTROL_AF_MODE, not CONTROL_MODE? The latter doesn't affect the type of autofocus used, and I'm assuming you want to do AF_MODE_AUTO for a touch-to-focus operation.

If you want manual focus, you'd need to set AF_MODE_OFF to disable autofocus.

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't really understand how to use focus, but i really want to set a specific focus to a specific distance at the  preview start and DON'T change this focus after by touching screen.

Comment: If you want a specific fixed focus distance, that only works on devices with well-calibrated manual focus modes. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INFO_FOCUS_DISTANCE_CALIBRATION is CALIBRATED).  But you can probably get close with APPROXIMATE.  Set AF_MODE to OFF, and then set LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE to what you want, and set that as the repeating request.

Comment: It's quite strange.. the calibration returns null and focus manual focus doesn't works even if i have set AF_MODE off and set focus distance.